# triggering a function after Fullcalendar eventAfterAllRender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have my fullcalendar script in a separate file and it already has "eventAfterAllRender" set.

Now in another js file, I try to trigger clicking on a button on the page on the load, where there is a fullcalendat on the same page too.

So, when i run the code, on the load, the events are not rendered. what i want is to have something like

```
$("calendar").fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: function() {$("#button").click();}
})
```

but what happens is that it overwrites the already existing default function in eventAfterAllRender for my fullCalendar.

What I want is to extend `eventAfterAllRender` option in my `fullcalendar` and
 `$("#button).click()` after the default function in eventAfterAllRender is executed.

How is it possible? :)

Answer (score 5):

In your code you have two mistakes.

```
$("calendar").fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: function(){
        $("#button").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes.. i wrote it wrong in here, sorry.. was in rush.. but in the original code, it is right.. but still it override the code..